# copy entire row from sheet1 into sheet2 matching ID and column header

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheet1
    ID  First   Last     Street              City        State  Zip
   ---  -----   ------   -----------------   ----------  -----  -----
    51  Alfred  Obrien   636 Charla Lane     Richardson   TX    75081
    52  Donald  Lemmons  4956 Center Street  Umatilla     OR    97882
    53  Corrine McCann   3149 West Street    Grand Rap    MI    49546
    54  Monique Gavin    4078 Maryland       Largo        FL    34640
    55  Steven  Murray   965 Tree Top Lane   Lansdowne    PA    19050
    56  Kelley  Robins   1191 Earnhardt      Louisville   KY    40223

Sheet2
    ID  Zip     State    Last    City     first      Street  Zip
   ---  -----   ------   -----  ------    ------     -----   -----
    56
    51
    87
    52
    55
    53
    54
```

need to copy the data row wise depends on ID(unique) if ID matches copy and paste the row at the same time column header should match. if you observe column headers are same but position is different in sheet2.

i got vlookup formula but#N/A is getting whenever if ID doesn't match which is overwriting the data.. so i need VBA code

Comment: show what's _"receiving an #N/A error "_

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the following formula with your example:

Place it inside of Sheet2 > Cell B2

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE)
```

Here we **lookup cell A2**, from the **range Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7**, then we **return the value on the second column**, FALSE = **Exact match**

Here's to avoid #N/A errors with a custom message.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE), "CUTOM ERROR MESSAGE")
```

If vlookup **result is a number**, **use the vlookup**, else, **use custom error message**.

Here's a sample that displays what ever is in Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7 **if there is a match** and **if there is not**.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE), VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$7,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: i already had vlookup formula but the problem here is the data should not overwrite in the cell for which ID not matches..if ID got matched with sheet 1 then entire row will be copied but that formula again gives #N/A if ID not matched..unmatched ID is having some data which is important & should not overwrite with #NA

Comment: =VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet3!$A$1:$G$16,MATCH(B1,Sheet3!$A$1:$G$1,0),0)     i used Vlookup to solve this already and i converted into VBA code

Comment: What do you want to display if it does not match?

Comment: i dont want to display nothing.. if it doesnot match it should not change cell data.. like cell contains some text .if it doesnot match with ID, it should reflect the data contains in that cell

Comment: Ok. One moment. Updating answer.

Comment: =VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$16,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0),0)                                                                                                                                this is my vlookup formula which is working perfectly but request you to modify if u can according to the requirement(data should not overwrite in the cell if doesnt match) which i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If doing this with code you need to specify the conditions under which to ignore inputing a value into a cell. Then create a loop to test cells against this condition before evaluating the result to input or ignoring the cell.

The result to input can be based on the same logic as the sheet formula shown below.

An efficient way is with `index` and `match` to get the row and column within the lookup table so if your data started in A1 in both sheets, you would put the following in sheet 2 B2 and drag to fill the other cells.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$G$7,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH(Sheet2!B$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0)),"Not found")
```

[image: Lookup formula]

Taking ID 56 as an example, the formula first indexes the lookup table in sheet 1. That means you can retrieve items specifiying row and column arguments.

To find the row, the formula seeks to match the ID by looking at column A (I have limited the range to only those rows you are using) and returns the row number where found, if found. Likewise, the column is found by matching Zip with row 1 in sheet 1 and returning the column where found.

So for `ID 56` you get

`Sheet1!$A$1:$G$7` as lookup range

`MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,0)` = 7 as row

`MATCH(Sheet2!B$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0)` = 7 as column

So `INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$G$7,7,7)` = ZIP `40223`

Wrap this in an IFERROR in case matches not found. In the example here, "Not Found" is returned.

Comment: i should not get "Not Found" error if doesnot match.. it should remain same data which cell contains previously . in Sheet2  lot of ID's may be unavailable for monthly report which contains the data of unmatched ID's already so i dont want to overwrite that with #N/A if doesnt match

Comment: I think what you need seems to be some sort of VBA vlookup because you actually have data in Sheet2 which keeps your from adding VLookup formulas in Sheet2.

Comment: i already having VLOOKUP formula which i used already perfectly working fine, but the problem is some ID's having data already in sheet2 which changes to N/A after applying this formula (ID wont matches with ID in sheet1) if doesnt matches the cell data should remain same

Comment: =VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$16,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$1,0),0)           this works perfectly fine, but facing N/A when ID doesnot matchng..That unmatched ID is having some data already entire row is getting N/A. i want that data to display if ID not matched

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- "Sheet1" as the "source" sheet
- "Sheet2" as the "target" sheet
- headers at row 1, ranging form columns A to H (i.e. from columns 1 to 7)
- data ranging from rows 2 to 100

you could use this

```
Sub mm)
    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:H"))
        .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!R2C2:R100C7,MATCH(RC1,Sheet1!R2C1:R100C1,0),MATCH(R1C,Sheet1!R1C2:R1C7,0)),""Not Found"")"
        .Value = .Value
        .Replace what:="Not Found", replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole
    End With
End Sub
```

just adjust sheet names and columns/row starting/ending indexes to your actual needs

Comment: i already had vlookup formula but the problem here is the data should not overwrite in the cell for which ID not matches...i dont want to display nothing.. if it doesnot match it should not change cell data.. like cell contains some text .if it doesnot match with ID, it should reflect the data contains in that cell

Comment: did you _actually_ try my solution?

Comment: before trying requesting you to conform, where is the target "sheet2" in your code?

Comment: @harshakazama, sheet2 is assumed as the _active_ sheet. And your request to conform had nothing to do with it. And if you’d actually tried my solution you wouldn’t have written the comment about possible overwriting of cells with existing data. So, you may want to try my code and see if it fits the issue in your question.